# Html/Css - Replacing single or many lines with dots

Tags: jquery, html, css, replace

I created this jsfiddle, where the end of the first line is replaced with dots:

http://jsfiddle.net/U8DmL/4/

Code:

```
div#container {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    width:140px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

But what if i want to show two or more lines text?

And replace the second line with dots at the end?

Anybody got an idea? (Possible with html/css or jquery ? )

Comment: should i work with .outerHeight() jquery-function maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle with using jquery

See if it helps

```
$(function(){
 var content = $("#container").html();
if((content.length > 50 )) {

$("#container").html(content.substring(0,50) + "...")
}
```

})

http://jsfiddle.net/U8DmL/6/